# GraphQL not passing down root set during runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql

I am using graphql directives to authorize the user for the queries and mutations. I currently take the 'authorization' header and then inject the user object into the root.

```js
   Object.keys(fields).forEach(fieldName => {
      const field = fields[fieldName];
      const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;

      field.resolve = async function (...args) {
        const requiredRole =
          field._requiredAuthRole || objectType._requiredAuthRole;

        if (!requiredRole) {
          return resolve.apply(this, args);
        }

        const requestData = args[2];
        const strategyResult = await ruleStrategy(requestData, requiredRole);
        requestData.fruit = 'apple';
        console.log(args); // this prints all the objects injected into args with no problem
        if (!strategyResult) {
          throw new Error("not authorized");
        }

        return resolve.apply(this, args);
      }.bind(this);
```

However, when I try to get the injected objects inside the resolver, `root` is `undefined`

```js
  test: async (root, args, context) => {
    console.log(root); // this doesn't show the injected objects. :(
    return 'test';
  },
```

Where have been going wrong?

Comment: You're not modifying the first argument. You're modifying the third argument (context).

Comment: Okay, so the first argument is what sent to the resolver as root. RIght?

Comment: Yes, you can see the order of the arguments in your resolver: root, args, context, info.

Comment: Yes you are right. Cool